# Why is custom action for resource not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I have an AppleController

it has a def sliceme  method

when I go to: /apple#sliceme

it routes to #index

In my routes.config I have

resources :apples

Why?? And what is the correct route??

Comment: I at first thought this was a typo, but `/apple#sliceme` is going to go to `/apple` and then look for an html element with an id of `sliceme`.  If you want an actual page, use `/apple/sliceme`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resources will create the CRUD method routes (see [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions))

If you want to specificity another route you can specify it like so in your routes file:

```
get "apple/sliceme", to: "apple#sliceme"
```

Or

```
resources :apple do
  get :sliceme, on: :collection
end
```

To check what routes actually exist, run `rake routes` in the terminal

Comment: Neither worked. AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'show' could not be found for AppleController). Nor do I want a show method, I want the sliceme method to work.

Comment: what does rake routes spit out?

Comment: sliceme_apple GET    /apple/:id/sliceme(.:format)      apple#sliceme

Comment: I was using `:member` instead of `:collection`. But also I commented on the question